# TextLocal Integration for OTP Verification is not working with supabase and flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, supabase, supabase-flutter, textlocal

I am using Supabase for OTP Verification in my flutter project. I added textlocal as provider in Supabase auth . I already registered sms template in both DLT and Textlocal side.I added all the necessary details at Supabase side also (such as API Key, approved Sendername etc)

Now, Whenever I try to send OTP using signInWithOTP() method available in Supbase SDK for flutter. It generates an error "AuthException(message: Error sending sms OTP: , statusCode: 400)" .

But When I try to send sms through textlocal dashboard ,it works fine .

Comment: Within your Supabase dashboard under logs, you should be able to see more logs of what might be causing the issue.